# Obtain a mask for similar elements in two arrays and apply it to a third one

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of floats

```
x1 = [3418.008 3422.007 3424.007 3425.995 3428.026 3430.003 3539.979 3541.957
 3650.041 3654.06  3656.062 3658.066 3660.019 3662.024 3664.024 3666.041
 3667.985 3669.976 3672.009 3674.007 3767.969 3769.959 3771.959 3773.976
 3775.975 3777.974 3779.97  3781.993 3784.002 3785.993 3787.991 3789.998
 3791.997 3794.022 3882.009 3884.043 3886.036 3888.028 3890.007 3890.007
 3892.015 3894.018 3895.983 3897.987 3903.978]
```

and one, of different length, of integers

```
x2 = [2870 2871 2872 2873 2874 2875 2876 2877 2878 2879 2880 2881 2882 2883 ... 3936 3937 3938 3939 3940 3941].
```

They both represent times, as measured by two different instruments at different sampling rates.
To x2 also corresponds another array of the same length,

```
y2 =[ 9.000e-04 -1.000e-03  4.000e-04 -2.000e-03  1.000e-04 -1.600e-03 ... 1.200e-03  3.100e-03 -1.000e-03  6.000e-04]
```

(that contains also zeroes and negative numbers). This represents the variable quantity measured as a function of time x2.

I want to obtain a modified version of the y2 such that it contains only elements correspondent to x2 values that are closest to the x1 closest element.
If the x2 closest element to x1 is negative, zero, or their difference is larger than epsilon, the correspondent value in y2_mod should also be removed.

I guess this means to apply some sort of mask to x2 through x1, get indices for that or maybe apply the same mask to y2?

Comment: I have left an answer based on my interpretation of the question. You're trying to get the values of `y2` which are sampled at the nearest points to times in `x1`, so for example at `x1=3418.008` the closest point would be `x2=3418` at index `idx`. From here you want to take `y2` at that index `y2[idx]` and throw it into `y2_mod`. Repeat this for all values in `x1` then apply a mask such that `0 < x2 <= eps`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**
I think I misunderstood the question the first time around, try this.

To find the closest elements you can use `np.meshgrid` to translate the problem into two dimensions and get a distance matrix between the arrays:

```py
xx1, xx2, = np.meshgrid(x1, x2)
dist = np.abs(xx1 - xx2)

idx = dist.argmin(axis=0)
x2_mod = x2[idx] # same shape as y2_mod
y2_mod = y2[idx] # same shape as x2_mod
```

From here you can apply masking conditions to your arrays based on negative values and epsilon:

```py
mask = (y2_mod >= 0) & (dist.min(axis=0) < eps)

y2_mod[mask]
```

From your most recent comment about averaging negative values:

```py
# convolve your signal with an averaging kernel
kernel = [0.5, 0, 0.5]
avg = np.convolve(y2_mod, kernel, mode='same')

# apply boundary conditions (only consider one neighbor)
avg[[0, -1]] = y2_mod[[1, -2]]

# fill in the masked values
mask = y2_mod < 0
y2_mod[mask] = avg[mask]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure I am following what is happening here. The `x2_mod` returned seems right, but `x2_mod < eps` does not exclude possible outliers, and `y2_mod[mask]` results empty. I have edited the original question to make it clearer that epsilon refers to the difference between the element in `x2_mod` and its closest counterpart in `x2` (their difference needs to be small).

Comment: Oh that makes sense. I will edit my answer to reflect this new info.

Comment: Thanks. Now it seems to work better, but the length of the two arrays `x2_mod` and `x1` differs of 1 unit with `len(x1) > len(x2_mod)`. They should be the same because, basically, x1 is the mask that filters x2.

Comment: I've moved the epsilon condition to be applied only to y2_mod. That was the only change, now x2_mod is the same length as x1.

Comment: I'll try it soon and let you know/accept the answer, but I have the impression it will work good. Thanks.

Comment: Apparently the y2_mod still have some negative values. I will try to understand why, in the meanwhile please give me any helpful advice.

Comment: Do you want negative values to be filtered based on `y2_mod`? If that is the case then I will modify my answer. Currently the line `mask = (x2_mod >= 0) & (dist.min(axis=0) < eps)` is only filtering `x2_mod >= 0` and from your comment I think you want it to read `y2_mod >= 0`. Answer has been updated to reflect this. If you want both conditions (although I don't see why the time axis would run negative) simply restore the original condition and add it using the `&` operator.

Comment: This is something I realized just now, not asked in the original question. So I am going to accept your answer. But if you could help (maybe in chat?), I'd need that if an item of the `y2_mod` is negative, it takes the value of the average of the two neighbours, or just the value of one neighbour in the case of the first and last element.

Comment: I've updated my answer to also consider this latest development. Just to warn you, this could get tricky if two consequtive elements are negative. If you anticipate this to be the case then I leave that exercise to the reader ;).